# how to set ufw firewall/iptable rules for a VPN Server to be explicit in allowing certain connections?

Tags: firewall

I want  to connect to a VPN.  I want to enable  ufw firewall or iptables  so that there is no connection that  goes out  of  the VPN tunnel or that comes in (except that for VPN server).  Could  you  tell me  how to get this  with ufw or iptables? Allowing only the connection to  the  vpn obviously

Answer (score 0):

On a clean iptables config:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -N VPN
iptables -A INPUT -i $vpn -j VPN
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $vpn -j VPN
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
iptables -A VPN -j ACCEPT
```

Replace $vpn with the interface created by your vpn client.
Policy for the incoming packets:

- `-i lo -j ACCEPT` Accept packets from the loopback
- `-m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED` Accept connections already established.
- `-i $vpn -j VPN` The packets incoming from the VPN interface will handled by the newly created (`-N VPN`) VPN chain where you can define all the policy for the VPN. You could totally just accept the packets in this line and in the corresponding line of the OUTPUT chain but I think it's logically clearer this way.
- `-j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` Reject all the others.
- `-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` Also reject all forwards requests.

Comment: Ah sorry  could  i get the same goal,  with ufw firewall? (uncomplicated firewall). How  sould  i set it  to get  the same goal?